# Одинаковый размер при загрузке файлов через Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Здравствуйте уважаемые пользователи проекта!

Написал для сайта загрузчик файлов со своего статического сервера, и столкнулся со следующей проблемой: при загрузке разнообразных картинок у них указывается один и тот же размер 2 147 483 647 байт (a.bytesTotal) [Скриншот](https://www.ustatic.ru/img/41353679542.png) в то время как сами картинки весят в разы меньше. Не подскажете в чём проблема?

Некоторые из файлов которые пытался загрузить:
[16.jpg](https://www.ustatic.ru/img/attachment/1/16.jpg)
[8.jpg](https://www.ustatic.ru/img/attachment/1/8.jpg)

Дело тут явно не в http и https, поскольку пробывал и так и так.

Исходник AS3:

```
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.FileFilter;
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

var downloadURL:URLRequest;
var fileName:String = this.root.loaderInfo.parameters['fname'];
var file:FileReference;

function FileReferencedownload(a:MouseEvent):void
{
function closewindow(a:Event):void {
    ExternalInterface.call("UMBRELLA.plugins.mainWindow.thisclose");
    trace("Close event");
}
downloadURL = new URLRequest();
downloadURL.url = decodeURIComponent(this.root.loaderInfo.parameters['url'])+"?rnd="+Math.random();
file = new FileReference();
file.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, closewindow);
file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, closewindow);
file.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, function(a:ProgressEvent) {
    var b:Number = Math.floor(Number(a.bytesLoaded / (a.bytesTotal / 100)));
    loadlabel.htmlText = "<font size='12' color='#FFFFFF'>"+b.toString()+"% (Загружено "+a.bytesLoaded+" из "+a.bytesTotal+" байт)</font>";
    bar.setProgress(b, 100);
    if (b > 97) {
        cancel.visible = false;
    }
});
file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, function(a:Event) {
    closebutton.visible = false;
    downbutton.visible = false;
    loadbg.visible = true;
    loadlabel.visible = true;
    cancel.visible = true;
    bar.visible = true;

    cancel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(a:Event) {
        file.cancel();
        ExternalInterface.call("UMBRELLA.plugins.mainWindow.thisclose");
    });

});
file.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function(a:IOErrorEvent) {
    closebutton.visible = false;
    downbutton.visible = false;
    loadlabel.htmlText = "<font size='12' color='#FFFFFF'>Ошибка "+a.errorID+", файл не найден</font>";
    loadlabel.x = 55;
    loadlabel.autoSize = "center";
    loadlabel.visible = true;
    cancelerr.visible = true;
    cancelerr.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closewindow);
});
file.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, function(a:HTTPStatusEvent) {
    closebutton.visible = false;
    downbutton.visible = false;
    loadlabel.htmlText = "<font size='12' color='#FFFFFF'>Ошибка "+a.status+", файл не найден</font>";
    loadlabel.x = 55;
    loadlabel.autoSize = "center";
    loadlabel.visible = true;
    cancelerr.visible = true;
    cancelerr.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closewindow);
});

if (fileName=="undefined") {
    file.download(downloadURL);
} else {
    file.download(downloadURL, fileName);
}
}
downbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, FileReferencedownload);
closebutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(a:MouseEvent) {
ExternalInterface.call("UMBRELLA.plugins.mainWindow.thisclose");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте после начала загрузки, посмотреть на свойство `size` у объекта `FileReference`.

[size property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#size)

Comment: Благодарю, всё работает как надо.
Огромное вам спасибо!